# How can I go about visualizing the 6 frustum planes of a camera?

Tags: 3d, perspectivecamera

I have 6 planes defined as parametric equations of the form `Nx + Ny + Nz + d`. I would like some way of visually confirming that these planes are roughly what I expect. I understand that planes of this form have infinite extents so there's no straightforward way to generate vertices for them. Ideally I would like to obtain the 4 vertices of each of the 6 frustum planes of my camera generated from the 6 plane equations.

Comment: The tag [tag:opengl] is used for question related to OpenGL API and the tag [tag:directx] is used for question related to DirectX API. This question is not related to the OpenGL or DirectX API.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that planes of this form have infinite extents

It is a [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) with a near and a far plane:

[image]

The planes are infinite, but they are intersection. Each plan has a region defined by the intersections with 4 of the other plane. This polygons form the frustum and can be visualized. You can visualize the planes using lines along the edges of the intersection or using transparent surfaces.